# Rails web server isn't starting up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- Rails version 2.3.14
- Ruby version 1.8.7
- Gem version 1.6.2

`rails s` gives me the following output:

```
      exists  
      exists  app/controllers
      ...  
      exists  tmp/cache
      exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  db/seeds.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] Y
       force  config/initializers/session_store.rb
overwrite config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] Y
       force  config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
   ....
   identical  config/boot.rb
   identical  public/javascripts/controls.js
   identical  public/javascripts/application.js
   identical  doc/README_FOR_APP
   identical  log/server.log
   identical  log/production.log
   identical  log/development.log
   identical  log/test.log
```

My Rails version is really old, but it's not up to me. Also, my log files are empty.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails 2.x the command to run the server is

```
script/server
```

`rails s` in 2.x is creating a new rails app named "s", not starting a server.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 2.x use the following command in the project directory:

```
ruby script/server
```